# Method in trait not able to be called from controller

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I'm trying to use a trait to handle image upload on my Laravel application, but none of the functions in my Trait can be called from the controller.
It throws a BadMethodCallException and says that the function couldn't be found.

I've tried using really simple functions to test if it is a problem with the trait or whether the function itself has an issue, but even a simple return function that only contains

```
return "sampletext";
```

has the same issue.

The path of the trait is under App/Traits/UploadTrait
and I've already checked the spelling on the use statement in my controller, which says use App\Traits\UploadTrait;

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait UploadTrait
{
    public function test(){
        return "testtext";
    }
}
```

And the controller has

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

use App\User;
use App\Profile;
use App\Traits\UploadTrait;

use Image;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
...
    protection function updateProfile($args, Request $request){
    ...
        return $this->test();
...
```

Of course I expect the function in my trait to be called, but this does not happen.

Comment: Can you show us the structure? Where you've added the `use`, and where the `$this->test()` is called?

Comment: Done. I've added as much detail as I can without copy pasting everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the trait inside your controller and move the `$this->test()` inside a class function:

```
<?php

use App\Traits\UploadTrait;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    use UploadTrait; // <-- Added this here

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->test(); // <-- Moved this into a function
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `use` keyword to use that trait and its methods in the class

```
trait UploadTrait
{
  public function test(){
    return "testtext";
  }
}

class Controller{

}

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
  use UploadTrait;

}

$ob = new UserProfileController();
echo $ob->test();
```

You can make a function to and call the `trait` function.

[More Details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use trait inside the class like:

```
use my/path/abcTrait;
Class My class{
      use abcTrait;
}
```

Now, you can call trait functions with `$this->functionName ()` in functions.